# MVC5 Action Compilation Error: Not all Code Paths Return a Value

Tags: c#

I'm writing an MVC5 EF database first application and have LocationType as one of my entities.  When I wire up the controller's Action to get the various Locationtype entries, I receive the error stated above.  My controller action is as follows:

```
 public ActionResult GetLocationType()
    {
        FreightEntities freight = new FreightEntities();
        ViewBag.LocationTypeChoices = freight.LocationTypes.Select(m => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = m.LocationTypeID.ToString(),
            Text = m.LocationTypeDesc
        });
    }
```

What must be added in order to resolve the current error?

Comment: The method expects a return value of type `ActionResult`.  You're not returning anything.  It doesn't really have anything to do with MVC or EF, C# as a language requires that methods with return types actually return something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are adding data to ViewBag, you probably need to return a view:

```
public ActionResult GetLocationType()
{
    FreightEntities freight = new FreightEntities();
    ViewBag.LocationTypeChoices = freight.LocationTypes.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = m.LocationTypeID.ToString(),
        Text = m.LocationTypeDesc
    });
    return View();
}
```

Make sure there is a view on the right path according to the ASP.NET MVC convention. You can read more about it in this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view).